# Execution order of $(document).ready();

Tags: jquery

If I use $(document).ready() multiple times then what will be the execution order. Which code is executed first.

Comment: it is executed in the order in which they are added

Comment: document.ready() callbacks are called in the order they were registered. If you register your testing callback first, it will be called first.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883786/jquery-enforce-order-of-execution-of-document-ready-calls

Comment: Question is good but duplicate.

Comment: All will get executed and On first Called first run basis!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263385/jquery-multiple-document-ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code gets executed from the top to the bottom.

**HTML**

```
<div id="document-ready"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#document-ready").append("Document ready 1<br>");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#document-ready").append("Document ready 2<br>");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#document-ready").append("Document ready 3<br>");
});
```

**Output**

[image: Output (image)]

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vXQHH/)

**Explanation**

You see that it first outputs 'Document ready 1', which means that that one got executed first.

Comment: That code example is... strange.