# How to call an object within $(document).ready from outside it

Tags: javascript, jquery

The function is like:

```js
(function ($) {
 $(document).ready(function () {
  var MyObject = {
   MyFunction: function(){
    alert('I am here');
   }
  }
 });
}(jQuery));

MyObject.MyFunction();
```

How can I call it like above?

Comment: your MyObject variable will only be initialized once the document is ready. Why do you want to call it before that?

Comment: Where do you want the object available? Only within the scope(file) it's declared in? Or also in an external scope (file) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.ready()` callbacks are called in the order they were registered ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883786/jquery-enforce-order-of-execution-of-document-ready-calls)). One way to achieve your goal is to create a global object, then initialize it in one `$(document).ready()` and call it in a subsequent `$(document).ready()`.

```js
var MyObject = {};
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    MyObject = {
      MyFunction: function() {
        alert('I am here');
      }
    }
  });
}(jQuery));


(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
       MyObject.MyFunction();    
    });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You variable loses scope outside the event where you are declaring it.

Your code

```
  (function ($) {
   $(document).ready(function () {
    var MyObject = {
        MyFunction: function(){
            alert('I am here');
        }
    }
   });
  }(jQuery));
```

your declaration and outside any other scope defined by some other function that's scope not accessible by your function call

```
var MyObject
```

needs to be outside $(document).ready(...)

Answer (score 0):

So, you are after **option 1**.

```
// Option 1: Object in a gloabl scrope
var myObject = {
    myFunction: function(){
        alert('I am here');
    }
};

(function ($) {

    // Option 2: Object in a function scope
    var myObject2 = {
        myFunction2: function(){
            alert('I am here 2');
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Option 3: Object in a local (to the "(function ($) {") function scope
        var myObject3 = {
            myFunction3: function(){
                alert('I am here 3');
            }
        };

        //alerts 'I am here 2';
        myObject2.myFunction2();

        //alerts 'I am here 3';
        myObject3.myFunction3();
    });

    //alerts 'I am here 2';
    myObject2.myFunction2();

    //Uncaught TypeError: myObject3.myFunction3 is not a function - can't access a locally scoped function on a global scope
    myObject3.myFunction3();

}(jQuery));

//alerts 'I am here';
myObject.myFunction();

//Uncaught TypeError: myObject2.myFunction2 is not a function - can't access a locally scoped function on a global scope
myObject2.myFunction2();

//Uncaught TypeError: myObject3.myFunction3 is not a function - can't access a locally scoped function on a global scope
myObject3.myFunction3();
```