# Where to put the jQuery document.ready function if I'm using a Master Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, template-engine

I created a master by putting together various sections that repeat themselves in every page, I created a Head, Footer and menu section.

In the footer I put my scripts `<script src` tags. I have a `<script src`tag that contains a script that all the pages use, this script has a `document.ready` function.

I want to use another script like in this case is a datatables script in the example of the page it shows the script like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    scrollY:        300,
    scrollX:        true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging:         false,
    fixedColumns:   true
} );
} );
```

I want to put that script inside a javascript file and put it at the end of the page and not in the `master page footer section` because that script will only be used by one page, but since that script needs a `document.ready` function, can I create two scripts with a `document.ready` function? one before the other? what is the best practice to solve this?

Here is the script that is in all the pages

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#side-menu').metisMenu();



//Loads the correct sidebar on window load,
//collapses the sidebar on window resize.
// Sets the min-height of #page-wrapper to window size
$(function () {
    $(window).bind("load resize", function () {
        topOffset = 50;
        width = (this.window.innerWidth > 0) ? this.window.innerWidth : this.screen.width;
        if (width < 768) {
            $('div.navbar-collapse').addClass('collapse');
            topOffset = 100; // 2-row-menu
        } else {
            $('div.navbar-collapse').removeClass('collapse');
        }

    height = ((this.window.innerHeight > 0) ? this.window.innerHeight : this.screen.height) - 1;
    height = height - topOffset;
    if (height < 1)
        height = 1;
    if (height > topOffset) {
        $("#page-wrapper").css("min-height", (height) + "px");
    }
});
var url = window.location;
var element = $('ul.nav a').filter(function () {
    return this.href == url || url.href.indexOf(this.href) == 0;
}).addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('in').parent();
if (element.is('li')) {
    element.addClass('active');
}
});
```

Comment: Yes; you can call functions as many times as you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you have multiple $(document).ready(function(){ ... }); sections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327756/can-you-have-multiple-document-readyfunction-sections)

Comment: Additionally, calling $(document).ready() multiple times keeps the order of the callbacks you set. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883786/jquery-enforce-order-of-execution-of-document-ready-calls